# Unable to compile a functor template

Tags: c++

I'm trying to define a function

```
template<typename Functor> static void start(DataSize size, ThreadNum threadNum, Functor f)
{
    ....

    std::for_each<int>(allocated, size, f);

    ....
}
```

allocated and size are just int.

The caller calls the function

```
start(image.width() * image.height(), _threads, RGBHistogramFun<T>(image, hist));
```

and

```
template<typename T> class RGBHistogramFun
{
    ...

    void operator()(std::size_t i)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

I set T to int for the template. I'm trying to define std::for_each so that it calls RGBHistogramFun::operator(std::size_t i) for each integer from allocated to size. The operator() will use the index to manipulate its internal array data.

However, I'm getting compiler error something about xutility.

Comment: That's also not how for_each works, where did you get this definition ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

n3337 25.2.4

```
template<class InputIterator, class Function>
Function for_each(InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Function f);
```

> Effects: Applies f to the **result of dereferencing every iterator** in the range [first,last), starting
>  from first and proceeding to last - 1.

`int` cannot be `dereferenced`.